# Trying to implement ajax live search on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I suspect either I am doing something wrong or the tutorial that I am following is outdated. First I implemented a normal search as follows:

**controller**

```
def filter
    if params[:filter]
      @productions = Production.where('productions.status like ?', "%#{Production.statuses[params[:filter]]}%")
    else
      @productions = Production.all
    end
end
```

**index.html**

```
<%= form_tag [:filter, :productions], :method => 'get', :id => "prod_filter" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :filter, params[:filter] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Filter", :status => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

  <div id="fast_filter"><%= render 'fast_filter' %></div>
<br>
```

And then I started to implement a live jquery/ajax search doing some changes to the following files and creating a partial template.

partial template **_fast_filter.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Director</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @productions.each do |production| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= production.name %></td>
        <td><%= production.director %></td>
        <td><%= production.status %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', production %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_production_path(production) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', production, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And I added this in **application.js**

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click', "#fast_filter th a", function() {
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
    $("#prod_filter input").keyup(function(){
      $.get($("#prod_filter").attr("action"), $("#prod_filter").serialize(), null, "script");
      return false;
    });         
});
```

And the **index.js.erb**

```
$("#fast_filter").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("fast_filter")) %>");
```

I am using rails 4.2. Now when enter keyword in text field I dont see any live search as I enter the keywords nor do I get a proper search result.

Comment: You gave your `$.get` a `null` as the success callback.  It's not doing anything with the response.  Unless that is executing the response in a global eval.  In which case the question would be if you have any console errors.

Comment: @Taplar I checked chrome console. As I type in the text field I am getting this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: So that sounds like the response coming back has a syntax error it in that the global eval is erroring on.  You'll need to fix that.

Comment: could you please tell exactly where ? i have posted all the files. I am new to jquery

Comment: You posted the response that is coming back from that get request?  Where?